# Public domain scientific intelligence test available for use in research

Tags: intelligence, measurement, methodology, test

The [IPIP](http://ipip.ori.org/) is an example of a public domain scientific personality inventory that can be used for research.

- Are there any good public domain scientific measures of intelligence?

#### Requirements

- **Do not** link to the kinds of hits you get when you type ["free online intelligence tests" into Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=free+online+iq+tests) (i.e., tests where you can only do the questions and get summary normative feedback at the end)
- Full text of instrument should be available, ideally with some form of test manual
- Information about test has been published in a refereed journal
- Test is freely available for use for scientific purposes, and ideally can be modified, adapted,

Comment: Also see suggestions here to a similar question http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/199/free-online-intelligence-test-with-norm-table-high-reliability-and-must-be-pri?lq=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[PEBL](http://pebl.sourceforge.net/index.html#about) is a free open source programming language to help construct psychological experiments. A wiki and developer community provide some documentation and support.

PEBL has a [Psychological Test Battery](http://pebl.sourceforge.net/battery.html) of many common or simple psychological tests so you may be able to use it out of the box without constructing your own test. PEBL includes free versions of many accredited and popular psychometric tests.

> Many of them represent the only Free version of proprietory tests available anywhere. They include a free Iowa Gambling Task, a free version of the TOVA®, a free Wisconsin Card Sort Test®, a free version of Conners Continuous Performance task, and a number of other useful tasks, with more to come.

If one of the included tests does not suit your needs, you or a programmer can create your own tests with PEBL's programming language which is customized specifically to create psychometric tests.

Comment: PEBL has two main problems, 1. It isn't normed, which means the external validity is going to be very weak. 2. Standard computer hardware introduces random lag in timing measurements. Perceptual tests that measure raw neural speed and rely on millisecond measurements are meaningless. That being said, I love the idea of PEBL and I have been thinking of some creative ways to norm the results on the cheap...

Comment: I also think PEBL is great, but why is this the accepted answer? I only see some subtests that relate to IQ, but the PEBL tests don't meet your requirement #2, there are no norms. @Jeromy what did you end up using?

Comment: I just accepted the answer to show appreciation. I'm still open to further suggestions. For now, I'd still use proprietary measures for intelligence testing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Gf/Gc Quickie Test

The Gf/Gc Quickie Test Battery (Stankov, 1997) is a one-on-one administered intelligence test. It is designed for teaching purposes, but has been used in research.

> The Gf/Gc Quickie Test Battery is a collection of tasks used by
> psychologists to assess human cognitive abilities. It is derived from
> within the framework of fluid and crystallized intelligence (Horn &
> Cattell, 1966), which is outlined below. This battery is designed for
> teaching purposes and the scores obtained must not be regarded as
> reflecting an “intelligence quotient”.

Here is a link to the test items and administration manual:
https://klingenstein09.wikispaces.com/file/view/Sample_Cognitive_Tests.docx

Stankov, L. (1997). The Gf/Gc Quickie Test Battery. Unpublished test battery from the School of Psychology. Australia: University of Sydney.

Answer (score 2):

#### ICAR: INTERNATIONAL COGNITIVE ABILITY RESOURCE

This project is an attempt to develop a public-domain assessment tool for cognitive abilities. It is being developed by several leading researchers in individual differences.

https://icar-project.com/

You need to register to access a short measure of cognitive ability.
They have sample items and a range of resources.

Condon, D. M., & Revelle, W. (2014). The International Cognitive Ability Resource: Development and initial validation of a public-domain measure. Intelligence, 43, 52-64.

Answer (score 0):

[Quantified mind](http://www.quantified-mind.com/science) is a collection of many tests with published papers. Its free and batteries are easy to customize, but only works online and converts the raw measurements of each test into a score for that item.