# Free online intelligence test with norm table, high reliability, and must be printable?

Tags: intelligence, measurement, methodology, test

I am looking for a general intelligence test which meets the following requirements:

- available online for free
- there is a table which translates "points" to IQ (I don't want a hidden online evaluation)
- it should be a reliable test (I am not looking for any sample tests like [Mensa Workout](http://www.mensa.org/workout))

Perhaps I should add, that I don't want to use the test to measure intelligence. I am a mathematics teacher and just want to have a complete IQ test to develop some problems for my classroom about probability and statistics based on an authentic IQ test-design.

Comment: Of possible interest: [Public domain scientific intelligence test available for use in research](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/15/88).

Comment: I doubt that any DIY test will result in high levels of accuracy. These tests cost a lot of money to create and they are fairly elaborate. Self-administering them is, well, kind-of a crazy idea. Just knowing what the test measures gives you an advantage.

Comment: Best IQ test with a psychiatrist or Mensa or any professional person best qualified and Culture Fair IQ test on the standard 15

Answer (score 12):

---

**Online Test**: Try [iqtest.dk](http://iqtest.dk/). It is basically a copy of Raven's Progressive Matrices.

> This test is developed with the aim of measuring your Intelligence Quotient (IQ). The test is Culture Fair, i.e. it minimises the effect of cultural variables, such as language, mathematics, etc. The test is based on logic, but is furthermore designed to test learning capability, memory, innovative thinking and the ability to simultaneously address several problems.

The test measures the general intelligence - g.

The calculation of IQ is based on answers from more than 250,000 people.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find the table which translates correct questions to an IQ value.

Comment: @Julia they specifically say that the correct answers are not published, I suppose to prevent people from "beating" the test. So, it's probably not what you're looking for given that you specifically said "I don't want a hidden online evaluation"

Comment: @user189 I feel I had to remove my upvote in light of that fact... sorry! While this *is* a useful resource, it doesn't really meet Julia's requirements...

Comment: I don't know the assumptions for this test, but if standard assumptions hold, I think it can be used for the intended purpose. Normally, all questions have equal weight, the average score is 100 IQ points, and each IQ point equals 1/15th of a standard deviation of the distribution. This test will give you a total score in IQ points as well as a percentile score, so you can check if these assumptions are true.

Comment: Links are broken, going to update them with what I think are the correct ones from the same website.

Answer (score 4):

I just found out about ICAR.

> The International Cognitive Ability Resource is a public-domain
>   assessment tool which aims to encourage the broader assessment of
>   cognitive abilities in psychology and other social sciences and
>   facilitate neuropsychological assessment in medical research and
>   practice. The collaborators working on this project believe that the
>   best way to achieve this aim is by making it easier for research
>   scientists to employ flexible and unrestricted measures which have
>   been well-validated against one another.

https://icar-project.com/

It's designed for researchers and you need to register to learn about what is available and gain access to measures.